# Git clone to home directory with Powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, git

I used to work with `cmd.exe` on Win 10, but recently switched to Powershell.
With `cmd.exe` both

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\example
```

and

```
git clone https://github.com/user/example.git %USERPROFILE%\example
```

work like intended. Since `%USERPROFILE%` does not work in Powershell, I use `~` instead.

However, when I'm for instance in `C:` and enter the command `cd ~/example` in Powershell, I will end up in the folder `C:\Users\JohnDoe\example` (as intended).

But when I run

```
git clone https://github.com/user/example.git ~/example
```

the repo gets cloned not to my home directory, but to `C:\~\example`.

Is there a way to use `~` with the git clone command in Powershell?

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/user/example.git $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath('~/example')`

Comment: or you just use `$env:userprofile` instead of `%userprofile%`

Comment: Thank you! 
Although `$ExectionContext....` would take even more typing than just the normal path ;)
I guess I will go with `$env:userprofile` for now, but it would be nice if `~` works in all cases

Comment: I assume this is because of git, or is the culprit Windows/Powershell?

Comment: why would you need to use `~` when `$env:userprofile` works as intended?

Comment: if you really need it, you can use `$((resolve-path ~\Example).Path)`

Comment: I don't need to use `~`, it would just be nice if it worked (since it already partially works). And I'm used to it on my linux machine

Answer (score 2):

That is strange. You could create the directory first, then use tab completion:

`C:\> mkdir ~/example
C:\> git clone https://github.com/user/example.git ~/ex<[Tab]>
C:\> git clone https://github.com/user/example.git C:\Users\Josh\example`

or use the $HOME variable:

`C:\> git clone https://github.com/user/example.git $HOME/example`